# Unable to display error message in IE but can display in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a save button and on click of save, if the validation has failed it should throw an error 'Serial ID is required'.

This works fine with chrome browser but is not displaying in IE

HTML:

```
<tr id="errorRow" style="visibility: hidden; display: none;">
            <td colspan="5" align="center"
                style="border: none; padding-top: 10px;">
            <div style="color: red; font-weight: bold;">Serial ID is required</div>
            </td>
        </tr>
```

javascript:

```
$("#Save").on("click", function(e){
    $("#errorRow").css("visibility", "hidden");
    $("#errorRow").css("display", "none");

    //Validate
    if($("#form").val() == "")
    {
        $("#errorRow").css("visibility", "visible");
        $("#errorRow").css("display", "contents");
        return;
    }
});
```

Comment: Where is the button? Please post a complete minimal code.

Comment: Does it help if you stop using `visibility` and work with `display:none` and `display:block` instead?

Answer (score 1):

"Note: "display: contents" does not work in Edge/Internet Explorer."
Quote from...
https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp

Display block is more appropriate.

```
$("#Save").on("click", function(e){
$("#errorRow").css("visibility", "hidden");
$("#errorRow").css("display", "none");

//Validate
if($("#form").val() == "")
{
    $("#errorRow").css("visibility", "visible");
    $("#errorRow").css("display", "block");
    return;
}
});
```

Comment: Another source for the same data (as most people here don't think much of the out-dated w3schools) : https://caniuse.com/#search=display%3A%20contents